# Is it possible to edit or dedupe a CRL?

Tags: puppet, openssl

I have a Puppetserver with a CRL that is currently 8.5 MB in size. Using `openssl(1)` and `crl(1)` I can see that the CRL consists of ~ 180,000 separate revocations but also I can see that there are only ~ 20,000 unique serial numbers; some serial numbers have been revoked as many as 500 times.

Whilst there are clearly bugs galore that should be fixed, I'm left with this oversized CRL and one particular outstanding bug is that access to the CRL is not locked in any way so there is a race condition between one process updating the CRL and another reading it. I can only hope that reducing the size of the CRL to just contain each serial number once might minimise the time spent writing the CRL and the chance of a conflict.

Is it possible to edit a CRL?

For reference, see:

- https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-7744
- https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/SERVER-115

Comment: The CRL is created (and signed) by the CA that issues it.  If you have access to the private key of the CA you can make up a CRL using OpenSSL.  If not, you need to fix the CA that is creating it.  You have to ask yourself why you've revoked 20,000 certificates in the first place - have that many keys been compromised?

Comment: Part of the problem is that the CA (built into Puppet) will happily keep revoking certificates that are already in the CRL, this why the CRL is far bigger than it should be. As for the 20,000, that's normal really with dynamic infrastructure in AWS, etc. machines get created/torn down all the time and this particular CA has existing for just over 2 years.